# getting "index" of set element via iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

This question applies to both `std::set` and `std::unsorted_set`.

I have an iterator to an element in a set. I'd like to use the iterator to get an "index" for the element based on its location in the set.

For example, the indices for my set would be as follows:

```
int index = 0;

for(MySetType::iterator begin = mySet.begin(); begin != mySet.end(); begin++)
{
    cout << "The index for this element is " << index;
    index++;
}
```

I have tried doing arithmetic using iterators but it doesn't work:

```
int index = mySetIterator - mySet.begin();
```

Is there any way to use the iterator to get an index value like this based on its location in the set?

Comment: The correct way of getting a "distance" between two iterators is the [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) function. However, please read the answer Jack before using it.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use [STL distance](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance), namely `std::distance(set.begin(), mySetIterator)`

Please note that:

> Returns the number of elements between first and last. The **behavior
> is undefined** if last is not reachable from first by (possibly
> repeatedly) incrementing first.

Remark : Complexity is linear;

> However, if InputIt additionally meets the requirements of
> LegacyRandomAccessIterator, complexity is constant.

Answer (score 9):

`std::set` and `set::unordered_set` are *associative* containers, not *sequence* containers, hence the concept itself of index doesn't make much sense.

If you need to retrieve an index for an associative container then design should be changed (even because without a concept of least or most recent inserted element the indices in such containers are subject to change).

Comment: I only need an "index" to link elements (iterators) to set items in a way that can be written to file. In other words, I have a massive list of set iterators and I don't want to write the same redundant set element data to file. I'd rather write the unique set elements to one file and then an index for each element, linking them back to a particular set item.

Comment: The concept of index makes a lot of sense, e.g. `set<ChessPlayer> players`; `int RankOf(ChessPlayer player, const set<ChessPlayer>& players)`; `players.insert(newPlayer)`; `players.erase(retiredPlayer)`

Now how would you implement an efficient `RankOf` function?

Answer (score 7):

[`std::set` has just a `bidirectional iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator), which means you can't do what you're trying to do with `operator +` (or `-`). Those are only available to `random access iterators`, like `std::vector` provides.

You need to use `std::distance` to get the "index", and `std::advance` to move from the beginning of the set to the end.

```
auto distance = std::distance(mySet.begin(), someIterator);
auto it = mySet.begin();
std::advance(it, distance);

assert(it == someIterator);
```

Comment: What is the time complexity of distance() function in case of set? Is it O(1)?

Comment: No, since `set` only has a `bidirectional iterator`, `distance` has to walk the list. If it had `random access iterators`, it could be O(1).